# Uniqueness of a vector with the minimal Euclidean norm

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

Let $W_{n}=\{(z_{1},\dots,z_{n})\in \mathbb{C}^{n}: z_{1}+\dots+z_{n}=1\}$. Find $z\in W_{n}$ with the minimal Euclidean norm. Is it unique? Is $W_{n}$ bounded?

If my reasoning is correct, I need to find the minimal value of $a_{1}^{2}+\dots+a_{n}^{2} $ with the condition $a_{1}+\dots+a_{n}=1$ where $a_{k}$'s are real parts of $z_{k}$'s (the sum of imaginary parts is $0$) and the answer follows from Cauchy-Schwarz, the sum of squares equals ${1}/{n}$, so an example of $z$ satisfying the conditions is $z=({1}/{n},\dots,{1}/{n})$.

But I have problems answering the other questions, could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: What kind of set is $W_n$? Does it have any structure? Is it closed? convex? Look at $W_2$ : does the condition $z_1+z_2=1$ seem to force boundedness? What if $z_1, z_2$ are real? What is the object $x+y=1$ in the real plane? is it bounded there?

Comment: @uniquesolution It is a line and has no boundary, but how to phrase the proof for $W_{n}$? You can make one number arbitrarily large and adjust others? As for the first question, I seem to have no clue.

Comment: I'm sorry that I mistakenly thought that "Cauchy-Schwartz" suggested by Firefox's spell-check was the right spelling.  I've put your arguments into a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $W_n$ has a unique element $z$ with minimal Euclidean norm.
   OP's arguments are right.  To make them a proof, we apply [Cauchy-Schwarz on $\Bbb C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality).  Suppose that $(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in W_n$.
   \begin{align}
   \left|\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \cdot 1 \right|^2 &\le \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1^2 \\
   \left|\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right|^2 &\le \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1 \\
   1 &\le \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|^2 \cdot n \\
   \sum_{j=1}^n |z_i|^2 &\ge \frac1n
   \end{align}
   Equality holds (i.e. Euclidean norm of $(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ is *minimal*) iff $(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\alpha(1,\dots,1)$ for some $\alpha\in\Bbb C$.
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{i=1}^n z_i &= \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha \\
   1 &= n\alpha \\
   \alpha &= \frac1n
   \end{align}
   So $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\frac1n(1,\dots,1)$ is the *unique* element in $W_n$ with minimal Euclidean norm.
2. Using uniquesolution's idea, we construct an *unbounded* sequence $(w^{(n)}_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ in $W_n$ for each $n\ge2$.
   $$w^{(n)}_k=(k+1,-k,\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{n-2 \, 0's})\in W_n\quad\forall k \in \Bbb N$$
   It's clear that $\lVert w^{(n)}_k\rVert_2 > \sqrt2 k \to +\infty$ as $k \to +\infty$, so for each $n \in \Bbb N$, $W_n$ contains an *unbounded* sequence $(w^{(n)}_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$, so $W_n$ is *unbounded* unless $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e=(1,1,1,\cdots,1) \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Then $W_n$ may be described as
$$
            W_n=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : \langle z, e \rangle = 1 \},
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$.
It is easy to check that $\frac{1}{n}e \in W_n$. And, for any $w\in W_n$,
$$
        \langle w-\frac{1}{n}e, e \rangle = 0.
$$
Every $w\in\mathbb{C}^n$ may be written as $w=w-\frac{1}{n}e+\frac{1}{n}e$. Hence,
$$
         \|w\|^2 = \|w-\frac{1}{n}e\|^2+\|\frac{1}{n}e\|^2 \ge \|\frac{1}{n}e\|^2,
$$
and equality holds iff $w=\frac{1}{n}e$. So the unique element $w$ of minimum norm in $W_n$ is $w=\frac{1}{n}e$. That minimum norm is $\|w\|=\|\frac{1}{n}e\|=1/\sqrt{n}$. $W_n$ is not bounded because it is a vector translation of a subspace.